# How to extract a variable from an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the following equation:

$$NX^{n-1} - \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(\Delta_i + X) - \prod_{i=1}^{n}\Delta_i}{X} = 0$$

for X > 0.

I would like to get the value of X. Is there a way to get the value of X without trying different values of X until we get zero?

Comment: In general, $X$ can be a real or complex number, and there is no way to "try different values of $X$ until we get $0$."  In the generality stated, this is a problem in numerical analysis, and it cannot be solved with precalculus methods.

Comment: @saulspatz What is the best way to solve this equation?

Comment: There is no short answer to that question, and perhaps no answer at all in this generality.  If you multiply through by $X$ you get a polynomial equation, and you can Google "roots of a polynomial."    But the solution methods are numerical, and not comprehensible if you don't know calculus.  Some methods require a lot more math than just calculus.

Comment: Any difference between $N$ and $n$ ? What are the $\Delta_i$ ? Is $x$ supposed to be small ?